# Best approximation theorem. Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

$Y$ is a closed subspace of a Hilbert space $H$ and $x \in H$. To prove that $x \in $ orthogonal complement of Y if and only if $||x-y|| \geq ||x||$ for all $y \in Y$.

Necessary condition is easy to proof, but I am trying to prove the sufficiency. I tried with the Best approximation theorem but can not been able to prove that $x \in $ orthogonal complement of $Y$. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 
$$
\|x\|^2\leq\|x-y\|^2=\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2-2\text{Re}\langle x,y\rangle,
$$
or
$$
2\text{Re}\langle x,y\rangle\leq\|y\|^2
$$
for all $y\in Y$. Fix some $y\in Y$ with $\|y\|=1$. Then, for any nonzero $t>0$,
$$
2\text{Re}\langle x,ty\rangle\leq |t|^2,
$$
or (after dividing by $t$)
$$
2\text{Re}\langle x, y\rangle\leq t;
$$
as $t>0$ was arbitrary, we conclude that $\text{Re}\langle x,y\rangle\leq0$. But this works also for $-y$, and so at the same time we get $\text{Re}\langle x,y\rangle\geq0$. Thus $\text{Re}\langle x,y\rangle=0$.

We can also take $iy$, so 
$$
0=\text{Re}\langle x,iy\rangle=\text{Re} (-i)\langle x,y\rangle=\text{Im}\langle x,y\rangle.
$$
Then $\langle x,y\rangle=0$. As $y\in Y$ was arbitrary, we have that $x\in Y^\perp$.

Comment: Very elegant, thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help. These computations come naturally after you've dealt with Hilbert spaces for a while.